# Shell in C - how to read and execute user input?

Tags: c, shell, execvp

My assignment is to write a very simple shell in C. I don't have many sources given and I have just started learning C, I have used only `scanf()` and `printf()` and coded simple functions. I only know it supposed to be written with `fork()` and different `exec()`. I spent a lot of time analyzing other shells, but I don't understand the structure of programs and some functions, like:

1. parsing, why do we need parsing? If I know I won't use arguments in commands, I would like only to compare input with my own functions like `help()` or `date()` and execute them.
2. reading user input. Using the `fgets()` and then `strcmp()`?
3. executing, how does it works? How `execvp()` knows that the user input is a command(function) in my `main` or program in my program folder?

Comment: Break it down into smaller parts, and learn each small part one by one. For example, what does `fork` do? What does it return? How does it work? What are parent and child processes? Experiment with `fork` and processes, until you get how it works. Then when you know about `fork` then move on to the next part. And so on. Before you know it you will have enough knowledge about each small part, that it becomes a simple puzzle and all you have to do it put the pieces together. And [here's some very related reading](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) about that subject.

Comment: exec takes a list of arguments.  Parsing is what converts your command string to that list.

Comment: Suggestion: avoid scanf.  You will spend a lot of time debugging arcane issues of the format string and not learn anything useful.  Use `fread` and `fgetc` family of functions for your input.  Learning to use these will be far more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say this sounds like a daunting task for a person just learning C, unless it's very carefully restricted. It does not make sense for you to need to analyze other shells. I'd advise you **talk to a teaching assistant** about the scope of the assignment, and what you're expected to do given your experience.

To answer your questions, though:

> why do we need parsing?

Parsing is (in this context) taking a sequence of characters and producing a data structure which your proagram can work on. Now, this could be a rather simple structure if there are not supposed to be any arguments, no multiple commands per line etc. However, you at least have to *make sure* that the user has indeed not used arguments, not written down an invalid command line, closed their open parentheses and so on.

> If I know I won't use arguments in commands

The program is not written for the perfect user whose behavior you can predict. You must accommodate any user, who may insert just about anything; you'll need to notice this case and report an error.

> reading user input. Using the `fgets()` and then `strcmp()`?

Remember that `fgets()` may not get through the entire line - if the line is longer than your buffer length minus 1. But perhaps you are guaranteed a line length limit? Or are allowed to fail on overly long lines?

Also, it might be the case that the user is allowed to use extra white-space as part of the line, in which case `strcmp()` might not give you want you want.

> executing, how does it works? How execvp() knows that the user input is a command(function) in my main or program in my program folder?

Have a look at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) for `execvp()` (and friends). Basically, what happens when you call `execvp()` is that the binary at a specified location gets run, and its command-line is what you pass as the second argument of `execvp()`. Suppose you run

```
execvp("/path/to/foo", "/path/to/foo", "bar");
```

so, the program at `/path/to/foo` is run. Like any program, its `argv[0]` is the path to itself. Its `argc` will be `2` and its `argv[1]` will be `"bar"`. Its working directory (and user and group id) will be the current directory, and user and group id, of the process which ran the `execvp()`, so - not necessarily `/path/to/foo`.

Continuing the previous example, you could do:

```
chdir("/path/to");
execvp("foo", "foo", "bar");
```

at which time `foo` would run with `argv[0]` being `foo`.